# Solving the integral $\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{dx}{1+\sin^2(\tan x)}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{dx}{1+\sin^2(\tan x)}$$

First, I tried to set

$$t=\tan x$$

Then I got $$\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{(1+t^2)(1+\sin^2t)}$$

applied a trig identity, $1+ \sin^2t=\frac{1}{2}(3-\cos2 t)$

I got

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{(1+t^2)\left(\frac12(3-\cos 2t)\right)}$$

I don't know how to keep going to solve it.

can some one give me a hint?

Thanks

Comment: $1+ \sin^2t=\frac{1}{2}(3-\cos t)$? it should be $1+ \sin^2t=\frac{1}{2}(3-\cos 2t)$

Comment: @Krish yes, you are right. But I still don't have any good idea to solve it

Comment: Do you want to have a closed form solution to this integral? Because after looking at this [Wolfram alpha answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cfrac%5Cpi2%7D%5Cfrac%7Bdx%7D%7B1%2B%5Csin%5E2%28%5Ctan+x%29%7D), I am not sure there is one.

Comment: @M.N.C.E. thanks for sharing the link